# Programmatically set constraints against safeAreaLayoutGuide on UIView

Tags: ios, swift5

I'm trying to set my constraints against "safeAreaLayoutGuide" programmatically, but it seems like safeArea isn't available in the "init" method of the UIView.

```
required init(foo: foo) 
{
    super.init(frame: .zero)

    self.addSubview(contentView)

    var layoutGuide: UILayoutGuide = self.layoutMarginsGuide
    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        layoutGuide = self.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    }

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor),
        contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.rightAnchor),
        contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leftAnchor),
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
    ])

    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

So when these constraints are set, the frame of "layoutGuide" is `{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}` so clearly something isn'r right here (unless on a decice below iOS 11).

I tried overriding the `safeAreaInsetsDidChange` function, and setting constraints there, but it seems like that function is too late, like the view will be initially wrong, then updated correctly

Where/when should I set my constraints on a UIView?

Answer (score 0):

You may setup the view inside `viewDidLoad` method instead of `init`

Comment: Then I would have to set up the constraints in the view controller, I'd like to be able to set them directly in the UIView